# Phone number regex should start by 0

Tags: php, regex

I would like to have regex, to validate this format of phone number : 
01 45 78 45 78

- Should be start by 0
- Have space after two numbers

**Example :** 
    491749192 **NOK**
    06 58 36 53 48 **OK**

Actually that's my regex :

```
^\d{2}(?: ?\d+)*$
```

Advance Thanks,

Comment: `^(?=0)\d{2}(?: \d{2})*$`?

Answer (score 0):

Just check if your first character is a 0 instead of any digit, and then check that all characters after that are sequences digits preceded by a space.

`^0\d(?:\s\d{2})*$`

[Here's a runnable example](https://regex101.com/r/68wUiA/1)

Answer (score 0):

As there are 10 digits in the example, you could start the match with a zero and a digit, and repeat the space followed by 2 digits 4 times to prevent matching only 2 digits.

```
^0\d(?:\h\d+){4}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kBgycu/1)